# naming a string array in a xml file in android studio gives me an error

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyaBJ.jpg)

There is a problem in name = "pieces"

Comment: Thank you so much it is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the studio is not giving you much error info try to clean and rebuild and see if that fixes your problem.

Pasting as answer in case in future someone refer this and miss the comment.